# Kill a java thread by thread name

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a script that runs every 15 seconds and it creates a new thread every time. Now and then this thread gets stuck and blockes the synchronisation process of my program. Now i want to kill the process with a specific name if the thread is stuck for 20 loops. Here is my code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        Date dNow = new Date( );
        SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println(ft.format(dNow));

        ThreadGroup currentGroup = Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
        int noThreads = currentGroup.activeCount();
        Thread[] lstThreads = new Thread[noThreads];
        currentGroup.enumerate(lstThreads);
        boolean loopthreadfound = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < noThreads; i++){
        try{    
        if (lstThreads[i].getName() == "loopthread"){loopthreadfound = true;}           
        }catch(Exception e1){System.out.println(e1);}
        }

        if (loopthreadfound == false){
            loopthreadcounter = 0;
            //Starten in nieuwe thread
            Thread loopthread = new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                try {
                    checkonoffline();
                    checkDBupdates();
                    } catch (JSONException | SQLException | IOException e1) {
                    System.out.println(e1);
                    }
            }

            };

            loopthread.setName("loopthread");
            loopthread.start();

        }else{

            loopthreadcounter++;
            System.out.println("Loopthread already running...   counter: " + loopthreadcounter);        

            if (loopthreadcounter > 20){

             // HERE I WANT TO KILL THE THREAD "loopthread "

            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to kill it by name? Why not keep a reference to the thread, and kill it (somehow) by reference?

Comment: Also fine... I just want to get it killed somehow. Suggestions how to adopt the code?

Comment: Also, how are you killing the threads? If you're using `Thread#stop()`, that's unsafe and deprecated. I would instead just send the threads an interrupt signal, and have them check for it periodically.

Comment: "*Now and then this thread gets stuck*" Why not just fix this underlying issue ...?

Comment: can the `checkDBupdates` operation be interrupted at all? You could try and call `loopthread.interrupt()`. Will the thread die?

Comment: This isn't a very good question which is why it isn't being accepted. More specific questions tend to much easier for people to answer and thus add value to the site. Instead of "What now?" perhaps try simpler code and tell us why it doesn't do what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

In general, thread names are not unique. If you are associating a `String` with a `Thread`, and that string identifies the thread you want to stop, keep track of it yourself, instead of treating it as the thread name.

That is, create a `Map<String, Thread>`. Later, you can get the correct thread from the map by "name" and terminate it.

Note that `stop()` is deprecated. You should find the correct way to kill, interrupt, or otherwise terminate the blocked operation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot kill threads in java.

So let's take a step back: You have a problem and you thought: I know! I'll kill the thread... how do I do that?

Wrong strategy. The most common way to 'externally' (as in, not from within the code in the thread itself) make threads end is to tell the thread to clean itself up. Whether it will, that's... where you write some code so that it'll happen.

For your case: Presumably some I/O operation is stuck. For most I/O and on most OSes, you can interrupt the thread; this causes an IOException to occur, thus 'unsticking' whatever was stuck. I'll show you an example. Instead of an I/O op, I'll be using `Thread.sleep` because interruptability is guaranteed by the java specification:

in the thread's code:

```
public void run() {
    while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
        doExpensiveOp();
        try {
            // sleep a long time
            Thread.sleep(1000000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

and in the controlling code:

```
Thread x = ... that thread.;
x.interrupt();
```

the interrupt method will 'raise the interrupt flag', and nothing more. However, many java core library calls interact with it. For example, *ALL* methods that are defined to 'throw InterruptedException' will immediately exit if they are sleeping as the thread is interrupted, and if the flag is up and you call one of these methods, they don't run at all, they instantly exit with that exception. We also check the flag's state in the while loop. So, the thread code above will definitely exit if you interrupt it, if we are in the sleep() op. If the thread is currently in the expensive op part of it, then one of three  things will happen:

1. This op flat out ignores it. That's certainly possible; only methods declared to throw InterruptedEx are *GUARANTEED* to deal with it properly. At least, the moment the op ends, your thread will definitely exit, as the call to sleep will instantly throw InterruptedEx.
2. This op will deal with it. For example, by throwing an IOException with text 'interrupted'.
3. The op does something bizarre. It's, as the above snippet shows, just code. You can catch InterruptedException and do nothing, thus clearing the flag and not actually ending. The `interrupt()` method doesn't force close or stop anything, and there is no method on `Thread` you can use to forcibly stop it either. None of the built in code (stuff in `java.*` packages) does such things; they always either ignore it, throw `InterruptedException` is specced to do so, or otherwise throw a relevant exception; almost always `IOException`.